# Having issues with a function in C that verifies a strings length is in a certain length range

Tags: c, c-strings

I'm brand new to programming and having issues with my function so any help you could provide me would be much appreciated! Without using the string library functions, I'm trying to write a function using C that has the user enter a string with a length in a certain range, and keeps prompting for input until it gets a string with a valid length.

When I run my code for some reason the correct error messages are printing but only for every other incorrect string length input, it's just letting the user enter another string again. It is also when given a string with an acceptable length prompting for input again when it should have accepted it the first time but after entering it a second time it accepts it and stops. I have a screen shot showing an example of this behavior and as you can see, on the third line there is no error message printed after the second input of "abc" and after the valid string "abcdef", I have to type it in a second time to exit.
[Ex 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bceY6.png)

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void clrIBuff(void)
{
    while (getchar() != '\n')
    {
        ;
    }
}
void inputStr(char* str, int lengthMin, int lengthMax) {
    int i, length, flag = 0, valid = 0;
    do {
        flag = 0;
        for (i = 0; !flag && i < lengthMax + 1; i++) {
            str[i] = getchar();  // read one char at a time
            if (str[i] == '\n') {
                flag = 1;  // stop reading if newline is found
            }
        }
        length = i;
        if (str[length - 1] == '\n') {
            str[length - 1] = '\0';  // remove newline from input
            length--;
        }
        if ((lengthMin == lengthMax) && (length != lengthMax)) {
            printf("ERROR: String length must be exactly %d: ", lengthMax);
        clrIBuff();
        }
        else if (length < lengthMin) {
            printf("ERROR: String length must be between %d and %d: ", lengthMin, lengthMax);
        clrIBuff();
        }
        else if (length > lengthMax) {
            printf("ERROR: String length must be no more than %d: ", lengthMax);
        clrIBuff();
        }
        else {
            valid = 1;
        }
    } while (!valid);
}
int main()
{
    char testStr[7] = { '\0' };
    inputStr(testStr, 6, 6);
    inputStr(testStr, 4, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

I thought it might have the do with the function clearing the input buffer being called in each of the if statements but removing it also causes problems, just different from above. When I do that the error messages print every time but when the length is outside the acceptable range, the error message prints multiple times and for some reason 3 times in the last invalid string I tried.
[Ex 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4ZP1.png)

Comment: `getchar(3)` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll actually notice that with your current code, it will properly display the error message if the input string is too large, but in the other scenarios, it will play the error message every second time.

This is because you input a string, with the end of you input being `\n`.
Then your `clrIBuff` function is waiting for another `\n`, which is eating up your entire other input. I would suggest only running `clrIBuff` if the provided input was larger than the max length.

```
        if ((lengthMin == lengthMax) && (length != lengthMax)) {
            printf("ERROR: String length must be exactly %d: ", lengthMax);
            if (length > lengthMax) clrIBuff();
        }
        else if (length < lengthMin) {
            printf("ERROR: String length must be between %d and %d: ", lengthMin, lengthMax);
        }
        else if (length > lengthMax) {
            printf("ERROR: String length must be no more than %d: ", lengthMax);
            clrIBuff();
        }
        else {
            valid = 1;
        }
```

I also refactored the code you provided to be a little more readable, hopefully that can also be of use to you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inputStr(char* str, int lengthMin, int lengthMax);

int main()
{
    char in1[7], in2[7];
    inputStr(in1, 6, 6);
    inputStr(in2, 4, 6);

    printf("Input 1: %s\nInput 2: %s\n", in1, in2);

    return 0;
}

void inputStr(char* str, int lengthMin, int lengthMax) {
    int i, length, valid = 0;
    // Ask the user for input
    while (1) {
        // Add each char 1 by 1 into str until \n found
        for (i = 0; i < lengthMax + 1; i++) {
            char in = getchar();
            if (in == '\n') {
                str[i] = '\0'; // End the string
                break; // Exit the loop once \n is found
            } else {
                str[i] = in;
            }
        }

        // Store the length
        length = i;

        // Error checking
        if (lengthMin == lengthMax && length != lengthMax) {
            printf("ERROR: String length must be exactly %d: ", lengthMax);
            while (length > lengthMax && getchar() != '\n'); // clear the previous input if input was bigger
        } else if (length < lengthMin || length > lengthMax) {
            printf("ERROR: String length must be between %d and %d: ", lengthMin, lengthMax);
            while (length > lengthMax && getchar() != '\n'); // clear the previous input if input was bigger
        } else break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In trying out your program I added in a couple of "printf" statements to help zero in where the issue appears to be happening.

Following, was some test output showing the symptoms you described.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/CheckString/bin/Release$ ./CheckString 
Test #1: abc
ERROR: String length must be exactly 6: abcdef
abcdef
Test #2: abc    
ERROR: String length must be between 4 and 6: abcdd
abc  
ERROR: String length must be between 4 and 6: abcdd
abcdd
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/CheckString/bin/Release$
```

When testing out the program with various length strings, it became apparent that the custom buffer flushing function was really creating a second input prompt that you probably did not want.

```
void clrIBuff(void)
{
    while (getchar() != '\n')
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

Your purpose, evidently, is to remove any leftover characters until the newline character is sensed; however, that bit was already done in the "for" loop that was used to determine the string length.  So this function, in effect, executes another user input prompt.

Just to simplify the refactoring, a simple "fflush" used to replace the function body.

```
void clrIBuff(void)
{
    /*while (getchar() != '\n')
    {
        ;
    }*/
    fflush(stdin);
}
```

Effectively, nothing is happening here, but this gets the program through and onto a retry of the user input.  With that bit of refactoring, following is some test output at the terminal (including a bit of printed output to indicate which test is being performed).

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/CheckString/bin/Release$ ./CheckString 
Test #1: abc
ERROR: String length must be exactly 6: abcdef
Test #2: ab
ERROR: String length must be between 4 and 6: abc
ERROR: String length must be between 4 and 6: abcd
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/CheckString/bin/Release$
```

Give out that bit of refactored code a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: This is simply incorrect. `fflush (stdin)` is undefined behaviour.